# refresh (or redraw) one ROW from "datatables" component WITH inline editing

Tags: datatable, inline, editing, redraw

After days of searching I decided to ask experts :)

This is my problem :
I'm using datatables (from the excellent https://datatables.net) , combined with  inline editing function that are NOT provided by https://datatables.net

Inline editing is working well but 
I'm searching a method to recalculate some columns in the datatable component that are NOT on the DB (because this are calculated columns) :

Column A : 10 (manually edited if needed)
Column B : 15 (manually edited if needed)
Column C : SUM A + B

---

This is the Datatable script :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = 
            $('#mytable1').DataTable( {
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging:         true,               
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
            } );

            } );
        </script>
```

---

This is the inline editing script :

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
    url: "pb_update.php",
    type: "POST", data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj).css("background","#bee2bc");
                }        
           });
        }
```

---

This is a part of my table :

.....

```
<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'test','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $test; ?></td>
```

......

Help will be appreciated !!
Thanks a lot